# Optimisation of a system of inequality relations

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have a coding problem, which I have managed to reduce to the following form:

Given the constant values `min`, `max`, `a` and `b`, find a value `x`  such that:

1. `min <= |x+a| <= max`
2. `|x| >= min`
3. `|x + a - b|` is minimized

`min`, `max`, `a`, `b` and `x` are all floats.
I'm not aware of any algorithmic methods which treat problems like this one. The fact that all of the variables are floats makes iterating over all possible values impossible. Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: It's a bit unclear which are a-priori decided constants and which are optimization-variables. If only x are variables, the stated problem looks quite redundant (and potentially inconsistent / infeasible; e.g. min < 0 and max < 0 will falsify 2.; if i'm interpreting the absolute-value correctly here).  It might be overkill, but *linear programming* is a viable candidate (although some modelling tricks might be needed for absolute values).

Comment: Okay many thanks. Only x is an optimisation variable here, the others are all constants. I'll update the question

Comment: by "`|x + a - b|` is minimized" you mean the smallest possible value for `|x + a - b|`?

Comment: @bolov Why would a function `f(x)=|x+a-b|` be *minimized*?. @Lachy The whole absolute values everywhere hurt a bit (and it's amazing to see how i struggle reasoning about it although i do LPs all the time; way too many abs's). If we assume there is some oracle/solver for the problem without absolute values (e.g. LP), i highly recommend a-priori *expanding* all `2^n` combinations of the problem where each abs-entry has either an a-priori fixed factor of 1 or -1 -> e.g. solve problem (1 of 8) `min <= -1(x+a) <= max, 1(x) >= min subject to 1(x + a -b)`. This means: solve 8 LPs and pick the best.

Comment: `|x|<=a` is convex and easy to model as part of an LP. `|x|>=a` is non-convex and difficult. It can be solved using global NLP solvers or reformulated using binary variables (leading to a MIP).

Comment: This problem is one dimensional, so expanding the absolute values into LPs is basically "a small set of possibly open intervals". I have written a rough answer based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All functions in this problem are piecewise linear, hence the solution, if it exists, occurs at an endpoint of some interval.

The endpoints of interest of `x` are `min-a, min+a, -min-a, -min+a, min, -min` and `b-a`. We must keep those that verify the constraints, namely

```
|min-a|>=min, |min+a|>=min, |-min-a|>=min, |-min+a|>=min, 
min<=|-min+a|<=max, min<=|min+a|<=max 
and min<=|b|<=max, |b-a|>min.
```

Then for all points that are admissible, compute the objective and keep the smallest value.

This may not be the most efficient method (though for such a small problem efficiency is not really an issue), but it is systematic and can be turned to an algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over floats is infeasible but:

You can avoid the iteration by observing that a linear function like `f(x)=x-a+b` taken over an interval `x in [c,d]` always reaches its maximum and minimum at either `c` or `d` (the maximum might be +/- infinity if the interval is open).

Your problem can be transformed into iterating over a small number of intervals in this way. A rough outline below.

Observe that 2. means `x` is in either `[min, +infinity]` or `[-infinity, -min]`.

Condition 1. is a bit harder but it can still be expressed as a sum of intervals:  `x` is in either `[max(-a,min-a), max-a]` or `[max-a, min(min-a,-a)]` - that is if I didn't make a mistake expanding the absolute values. (Note the overload of `min()`, `max()` functions).

So 1. and 2. are sums of intervals, so their intersection is also a sum of intervals.

Now your target function isn't exactly linear, but it is close enough. It is linear on `[a-b,+infinity]` where it takes the form of `f(x)=x-a+b` and on `[-infinity, a-b]` where it takes the form `f(x)=-x+a-b`. So to find its maximum over an interval `[c,d]` you need to consider at most two intervals produced by intersecting `[c,d]` with either of the above intervals.